# How to set cellspacing in CSS on non-table elements set to display:table-cell?

Tags: html, css

How to set cellspacing in CSS on non-table elements set to display:table-cell?  http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/ysYZJ/

```
<dl>
    <dt>Definition title 1</dt>
    <dd>def detail 1.1</dd>
</dl>
<dl>
    <dt>Definition title 2</dt>
    <dd>def detail 2.1</dd>
    <dd>def detail 2.2</dd>
</dl>

dl {display:table-cell; margin:1em; background-color: #eee; vertical-align: top; padding:1em;} 
dt {margin: 2px 0; padding:1em; font-weight: bold;}
dd {margin: 2px 0; padding:1em; }
```

EDIT:
I am curious as to why `border-spacing` doesn't work in this situation?

Comment: Because `border-spacing` applies to tables, not table cells.

Answer (score 2):

Just using `display:table-cell` on an element creates an invisible (and anonymous) table around it. You can accomplish `border-spacing` for your DL tags by creating a DIV container for them with `display:table` and `border-spacing:(value)`

As BoltClock mentioned, the border-spacing style applies only to tables so you just need to create one that contains your table cells.

CSS

```
DIV {
  display:table;
  border-spacing:5px;
  border-collapse:separate; /* just to be sure */
}
```

As seen here in a modified version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nv4Fh/

Comment: I thought you would think that

Answer (score 0):

cell spacing basically set margin between cell elements, so you just have to do it yourself :

```
dl, dt, dd{
    background-color:#ccc; /* Just to see what's going on */
}
dl{
    margin-left:10px;  /* vertical gap cellspacing */
}
dl:last-child{
    margin-right:10px;
}
dt,dd{
    margin-top:10px; /* horizontal gap cellspacing */
}
dd:-child{
     margin-bottom:10px;   
}
```

Comment: In my research beforehand I found this too but nothing I have tried works. 'border-spacing' Doesn't work. Would you care to show me what I am missing?

Comment: I'm still working on it ;) Sorry, I posted the answer a bit too soon I guess... But why don't you use a table ? And if you're doing a layout, why don't you use float or margin ?

Comment: @Timidfriendly This will work. I notice that you have previous margin settings that you may have to adjust.

Comment: I applied your code and it doesn't seem to work, there is no space between the two DL cells http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/ysYZJ/5/

Comment: `:last` is not a CSS selector. Did you mean `:last-child`?

Comment: @BoltClock Yup, thanks. Timidfriendly, I switched the 1 for l... and I see space ... sure you're talking about DL tag ?